# react-native-sqlite-storage Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeModules["SQLite"][method]')

Tags: react-native, sqlite, storage

react-native-sqlite-storage Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeModules["SQLite"][method]')

I am getting this error when using react-native-sqlite-storage. I am using Expo to test my react-native app.

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
SQLite.DEBUG(true);
SQLite.enablePromise(true);
let db = SQLite.openDatabase(DataAccess.dbName, DataAccess.dbVersion, "Test Database", 200000, DataAccess.openCB, DataAccess.errorCB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably add everything in the android/app/src/main/java/com//MainApplication.java as described in the https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage
if you not add:

```
import org.pgsqlite.SQLitePluginPackage; // Add import

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication { 
...

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new SQLitePluginPackage(),   // register SQLite Plugin here
                new MainReactPackage()
    );
}
```

If you did that, then one more time rebuild the project and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

For React Native version > 0.60, following steps helped me for iOS:

```
cd <PATH_TO_PROJECT>/ios
pod install
```

Answer (score -1):

try not using expo, that solved my problem.